# Rails 3: convert session[:params] to correct activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models, Foo and Bar, with same attributes, and I'm 'caching' user "search params" into a session variable, that ends into something like this:

```
session[:search_params] => {"price"=>"15.0", "air_conditioner"=>"0", "fireplace"=>"0", "number_of_rooms"=>"1", "balcony"=>"0"}
```

I'd like to search both `Foo` and `Bar` for entries that match this query.

For now, I'm doing:

```
@foo = Foo.new(session[:search_params])
search_attributes = @foo.attributes
search_attributes.delete 'id'
search_attributes.delete 'created_at'
search_attributes.delete 'updated_at'
@results = Foo.where(search_attributes)
@results += Bar.where(search_attributes)
```

that is REALLY UGLY.

Could anyone tell me a better/the correct way?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Also, some params in the `session[:search_params]` that are "0", are actually 'false' on the database (booleans) (filled by checkboxes), so I have to do some "conversion" into this fields so that the `query` is done correctly, i.e., getting for example `air_conditioner => 'false'`    instead of   `air_conditioner => '0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't follow that path if I were you. I would go with a solution like https://github.com/ernie/meta_search

Comment: Thanks. I'll look this more closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Attribute-Based Finders: [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

So

`@results = Foo.find_by_price_and_air_conditioner_and_fireplace_and_number_of_rooms_and_balcony(session[:search_params])`

Also, you won't have to delete the extraneous information from `session`.

Comment: Thanks to answer. But isn't there something a little more "dynamic"?

Comment: If you want dynamic, I think what you've done is the best way.

Comment: Also, this code gives me the following error: `Unknown key: price (ArgumentError)`, where `'price'` is the first key on the `session[:search_params]`. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: I think I could use the code by doing: `Foo.find_by_.....(:conditions => session[:...]`. But this still doesn't fit my needs. Please, look at my edit.